# Exporting the output of an API as an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, fetch-api

I'm just getting started with REACT and working with API's. I'm trying to save the output of an API to an object "obj" and export it (later extract what I need from it and use it in a React component). When I import the object in another file and try to print it to the console I get "undefined". What am I doing wrong. This is the code:

```
const url= "someURL";
    
let obj;

fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => obj = data)
    .then(() => console.log(obj))


export default {
    obj
};
```

In the other file where I import "obj" :

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import obj from './Api';

function Company() {

    useEffect(() => {

console.log(obj)

    });

    return (
        <div className="centered">Your data is: {JSON.stringify(obj)} </div>
    )
};

export default Company;
```

Comment: you can't access data synchronously that is retrieved asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

You must create a variable that indicates whenever the data has been loaded or not.

```
const url= "someURL";
    
let obj;
let loaded = false;

fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => obj = data)
    .then(() => loaded = true)


export default {
    obj
};
```

Then you must pass that value to the component where you are trying to render the data.

```
render <Company loaded={loaded} />
```

And then when you render the comp

You should do something like:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';


function Company() {

    useEffect(() => {

console.log(obj)

    });

    return (
        {props.loaded ? <div className="centered">Your data is: {JSON.stringify(obj)} </div> : "loading..."}
    )
};

export default Company;
```

If you want to import and object and manage it globally without having to pass the props down. I recommend using redux-thunk / redux-saga for async global store requests